# Splitting strings that contain commas (special characters?)

Tags: regex, string, google-apps-script, google-sheets, special-characters

I'm working from a spreadsheet of values. I have code that pulls a row of content to analyze. I was planning to split it on commas, but some of the strings inside the cells include commas (that aren't regularly spaced, so escaping them would be difficult). I downloaded the sheet as a tsv instead of a csv and re-uploaded it, but my attempts to split on \t haven't been successful. (For good measure, I've also tried \n, \r, and \f to see if they're involved in delimiting cells. They don't seem to be.)

Is there a special character that means "next cell" or "next record" or something like that? Am I better off trying to end each cell with a particular character that I would then have to strip out of my data after splitting? I'd welcome any other ideas!

Code snippet:

```
var lastRowContents = dataSheet.getRange(lastRow, 1, 1, 21).getValues();
var contentChunks = lastRowContents.toString().split('\t');
var product = contentChunks[0];
Logger.log(product);
```

This outputs the entire row as one item in that array, like so:

```
product: Wed Jan 05 2005 02:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST),001-2005, Day-Lee Pride Beef Gyoza Potstickers,    Vegetable and Beef Dumplings ,misbranded,http://www.fsis.usda.gov/wps/portal/fsis/topics/recalls-and-public-health-alerts/recall-case-archive/recall-case-archive-2005/!ut/p/a1/jZDBCoJAEIafpQdYdlZN9CgLppa7SGS2l1gW0wVTMfHQ06d0MpScOc3w_XzMYIEzLGo56EL2uqllNc3CvkMCNnEpRNz3fAiZ6acOOxDg9gjcZoBLJiBN-JFScJi5Mb9SHvzLRxsERhfTuMCilX2JdP1ocNblSlYVUvKVI9mpUg_54hIZAHt8xWKuATL2qDlbQcRM4NYvsPCHL7B-aPu8ZO9TADr0dh-fh2db/?1dmy&current=true&urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2Ffsis-archives-content%2Finternet%2Fmain%2Ftopics%2Frecalls-and-public-health-alerts%2Frecall-case-archive%2Farchives%2Fct_index271,http://www.fsis.usda.gov/wps/portal/fsis/topics/recalls-and-public-health-alerts/recall-case-archive/recall-case-archive-2005/!ut/p/a1/jZDBCoJAEIafpQdYdlZN9CgLppa7SGS2l1gW0wVTMfHQ06d0MpScOc3w_XzMYIEzLGo56EL2uqllNc3CvkMCNnEpRNz3fAiZ6acOOxDg9gjcZoBLJiBN-JFScJi5Mb9SHvzLRxsERhfTuMCilX2JdP1ocNblSlYVUvKVI9mpUg_54hIZAHt8xWKuATL2qDlbQcRM4NYvsPCHL7B-aPu8ZO9TADr0dh-fh2db/?1dmy&current=true&urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2Ffsis-archives-content%2Finternet%2Fmain%2Ftopics%2Frecalls-and-public-health-alerts%2Frecall-case-archive%2Farchives%2Fct_index386,Day-Lee Pride Beef Gyoza Potstickers, Vegetable and Beef Dumplings,Produced 10/6/2004. The products subject to recall are: One pound bags of "DAY-LEE PRIDE BEEF GYOZA POTSTICKERS, VEGETABLE AND BEEF DUMPLINGS." Each bag bears the code "28004," as well as "Est. 17309" inside the USDA mark of inspection.,The packages state that the gyozas are filled with beef, but they may instead contain shrimp, a known allergen.,The problem was discovered by the establishment.,17309 M   Day-Lee Foods Inc.   13055 E. Molette St.   Santa Fe Springs, CA 90670,,Approximately 2,520 pounds,California, Colorado, Georgia, Maryland, New York, and Washington.,Class I,U.S. Food and Drug Administration (FDA),,,,,
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do... lastRowContents is already an array (2D array but easy to convert to straight 1D array...)

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear! I'm trying to assign the contents of each cell within the row to a variable of its own, so I need to break the row apart. Does that help?

Comment: since lastRowContents is an 2D array you have every cell with lastRowContents[0][0],lastRowContents[0][1],lastRowContents[0][2],etc...

Comment: Oh! I've never worked with 2D arrays before. would I be better off converting it to a 1D array?

That said, products (defined as lastRowContents[0][0]) now seems to be just "W".  If I define it as [0][1], I get just "e". I'm sure I could step through every character in the string this way, but that's not quite what I'm going for.

Comment: if the code above is what you actually use then lastRowContents[0][0] returns the first cell (I'm 100% positive about that), the result you have means it's a 1D array so try just 1 index [0], [1]... see answer below with link to doc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(just for visibility :)*

since `lastRowContents` is an [2D array (link to doc)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()) you have every cell with `lastRowContents[0][0]`,`lastRowContents[0][1]`,`lastRowContents[0][2]`,etc..

in your code :

```
var lastRowContents = dataSheet.getRange(lastRow, 1, 1, 21).getValues();
var product = lastRowContents[0][0];
Logger.log(product);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure I understand...I've tried lastRowContents[0], which spits out the whole row, and lastRowContents[0][0], which spits out just the first letter. You're saying that shouldn't be the case, right?

Comment: t shouldn't indeed... but you can use the single index it the result is what you need. :-)

Comment: Btw, I didn't invent anything, the documentation in the link is very explicit don't you think.?

Comment: Unfortunately, neither is what I need, really...the first cell here is "Wed Jan 05 2005 02:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST)" and at present my options are the whole row or a single letter, right? (As I mentioned, this is my first experience with 2D arrays...sorry!)

Comment: Of course you didn't invent anything! I have what I think may be your book right here on my desk and it's my go-to reference. I know you know what you're talking about; I think I'm not understanding it properly.

Comment: (he he... thanks :-) could you try the code I added in the answer and tell me what you see in the log ?

Comment: That outputs the full contents of the first cell!

It looks like you've just skipped the split() step and are referring directly to the array to define the variables, right? That makes a lot of sense!

Thank you SO MUCH for your help (and your patience!).